# hydrate an array of json objects, so that each json with different number of keys shares maximum keys

Tags: javascript

Is there a javascript library that can transform json like this:

```
[{},
 {title: ""},
 {title: "", author: "unknown"},
 {isbn: "234234"},
 {author: "n/a"}
]
```

and returns

```
[{title:"", author: "", isbn: ""},
 {title: "", author: "", isbn: ""},
 {title: "", author: "unknown", isbn: ""},
 {title: "", author: "", isbn: "234234"},
 {title: "", author: "n/a", isbn: ""}
]
```

It was a bit difficult to explain this so I am using an easy to understand example.

update: I do not know the property fields ahead of time. It is dynamic.

Comment: I do not know of a library, but here is a similar SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734131/clean-method-to-normalize-javascript-object-properties

Comment: @jwatts1980 thanks for that I think I may need to follow that

Comment: I solved this using the solution in @jwatts1980s link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one ?

```js
let origin= 
    [ { }
    , { title: '' }
    , { title: '', author: 'unknown' }
    , { isbn: '234234' }
    , { author: 'n/a' }
    ]

const modele = origin.reduce((a,c)=>{
  for(let p in c) if (!a[p]) { a[p]='' }
  return a
},{})

origin.forEach((elm,i)=>origin[i]=Object.assign({}, modele , elm))

// result
origin.forEach(elm=> console.log ( JSON.stringify(elm)))
```

Comment: The thing is I don't know all the property keys ahead of time also an update the provided data also comes in array like `{isbn: ["234234", "235234"] and may content objects as well;

Comment: i have no way of knowing what the property keys will be like. its dynamic.

Comment: @qimisle if the question was asked more clearly, maybe I will find a fairer answer

Comment: you are right i left that crucial part out ill update the question in full now

Comment: i like this solution as well its very easy to follow